# Silver charts axis intervals

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, charts, silverlight-toolkit

I have a number of Silverlight charts bound to datasets.

They all are working correctly however the values on the Axis display for years are showing, rather than full years, the points in between for example: 2007, 2007.2,2007.4 etc etc.

How can I make it so that it only show the full years?

Below is a screen shot to further explain visually what I mean.

[image]

Here is the code I use to bind the chart data:

```
foreach (var myVariable in UserSelections.TheDataSet.ER_Variables)
                {
                    var newSeries = new LineSeries
                                        {
                                            ItemsSource =
                                                UserSelections.GetDataRowsByVariableAndLocation(
                                                    UserSelections.GetIdForLocation(UserSelections.Locations[0]),
                                                    myVariable.Variable_ID),
                                            IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Year"),
                                            DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value"),
                                            Title = myVariable.Name,
                                            IsSelectionEnabled = true

                                        };
                    MainChart.Series.Add(newSeries);
                }
```

Comment: Can you show your chart definition code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the chart definition you need the following:

```
<toolkit:Chart Title="Chart Title" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <toolkit:Chart.Axes>
        <toolkit:DateTimeAxis IntervalType="Years" Interval="1"/>
    </toolkit:Chart.Axes>
```

I think this should do the trick (assuming that your date is actually a `DateTime` variable).

The key is you need to set the `Interval`.

*(Thanks to AnthonyWJones for pointing that out)*

Comment: That would work it the independant value is a datatime but by the looks of it, its just an integer.  Interval="1" is needed though.